# App not supported on some devices

Tags: android, google-play

My app doesn't support a specific android device (Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 10.1 P5210), though it supports other 10 inch tablets. I am clueless as to why this is happening. What could be the reason?

The client has the above mentioned tablet and my app doesn't get listed on his store.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app"
    android:versionCode="8"
    android:versionName="1.7" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

    <!-- Permissions for GCM -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="XYZ" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />

        <!-- Services and receivers for GCM -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.example.app" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.example.app.FFHBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="zecross.ffh.broadcastReceiver" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.example.app.NetworkStateChangeListener" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <!-- <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" /> -->
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.example.app.GCMIntentService" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.SwipingTaskDetails_Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_task_details"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.PostTask"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_task_posttask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.TasksForHire_Activity"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="True"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tasks_for_hire"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.SideMenu"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/TranslucentActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.MyTasks_Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_my_tasks"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.SingleTaskDetails_Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_task_details"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.Filter_Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_filter"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/TranslucentActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.TasksForMe_Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tasks_for_me"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.TaskDiscuss_Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_task_discuss"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.Errand"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_task_errand"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.Sitter"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_task_sitter"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.AdviceLessonsTutor"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_task_tutor"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.Handyman"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_task_handyman"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.Cleaning"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_task_cleaning"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.VirtualTask"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_task_virtual_task"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.AnythingGoes"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_task_anything_goes"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.ItemsAndServicesForSale"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_task_items_sale"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.MyTaskInteraction_Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_my_task_interaction"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.LocateVenueCE"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_locate_venue"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.LocationFilter"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_location_filter"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/TranslucentActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.SocialActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_social"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.ContactsList"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_phone_contact_list"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.Chat_Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_chat_activity"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.UserFBProfile"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_user_fbprofile"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.MyAccount"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_my_account"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.NotificationSettings"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_notification_settings"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.Preferences"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_preferences"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.ActivityNotifications"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_notifications"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.Notifications_Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_notifications"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.NoInternetActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_no_internet"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/TranslucentActionBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.InAppPurchases"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_in_app_purchases"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.Blocked_Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_blocked"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.SendFeedback"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_send_feedback"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.My_Ratings"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_my_ratings"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: show your manifest.xml file.

Comment: Kindly post your Androidmanifest.xml then i can check the issue. might be it will be version conflicts or device conflicts.

Comment: I've posted the manifest file. Thanks

Comment: Make sure that target device having camera. If not this app will not supported on.

Comment: The device has both front and back camera.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest you are specifying that your app requires openGL ES 2.0:

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

Hence it will run only on devices that do.

It's the only requirement besides the Android version, therefore I guess your Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 doesn't.

Besides, you might want to change your package name from `com.example.app` to something else.

Comment: The device does support openGL ES 2.0.

And the package name is something else. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the Camera Permission. When I removed that permission, my client's tab began supporting the app. But I still find it strange since the tab had both front and rear camera.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding back the camera permission as you need it and specify the allowed screen sizes on the manifest. I reccomend you to add this code under `uses-permissions` tag for example...

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" 
    android:largestWidthLimitDp="2560" 
    android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="2560" />
```

Hope it helps!